# How to get 'secret' of registered participant using composer cli

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have registered participant as user in CA, now I would like to fetch secret of registered user. is it possible if forgotten secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Secrets are issued one time and cannot be retrieved AFAIK.